# PHP Javascript How to Check for minimum quantity

Tags: javascript, php

How to check or compare values? This is my code below. I am suspecting that the problem lies with the "$qty". I cannot compare $qty and $min... for some reason.. what am I doing wrongly?

```
<label for="qty">Enter Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="e.g 50" name="qty" id = "qty">
    <div id="Result"></div>

<script>
$('#qty').on('keyup', function () {
    var timer = null;
    clearTimeout(timer); 
    timer = setTimeout(check, 500)
});

function check(){
  var $qty = $('#qty');
  var $min = "50";

  if($qty<$min)
    $("#Result").html("Not enuf Qty");           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#qty')` selects an **object**. To get the value of a `input` use

```
$('#qty').val();
```

Also it is a good idea to compare **numbers** instead of **strings**:

```
var $qty = parseInt( $('#qty').val() );  // convert value to int
var $min = 50;                             // use int value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! It works but.. I noticed a mistake
 It is $('#qty').val() instead of $('#qty').value() !

Comment: Oh, sure, it's `val()`, my mistake, fixed).